# JSF bookmarking problem

Tags: jsf

I have a h:datatable that display employees data.
I want the user when click the employee name to navigate to a new page which URL looks like

```
employees?id=<some id>
```

I've tried to combine JSP EL with JSF EL, but no way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not on JSF 2.0 yet, then you can just make use of `h:outputLink` in combination with `<f:param>`, `#{param}` and `faces-config.xml`.

Basic table example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.employees}" var="employee">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputLink value="employees.jsf">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{employee.id}" />
            <h:outputText value="View employee #{employee.name}" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Basic `faces-config.xml` example:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>employeeManager</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.EmployeeManager</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>id</property-name>
        <value>#{param.id}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Basic `com.example.EmployeeManager` example:

```
public class EmployeeManager {
    private Long id;
    private Employee employee;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.employee = employeeDAO.find(this.id);
    }
}
```

The `@PostConstuct` annotated methods will be invoked **after** bean construction and all of injection and managed property setting. Also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#PassingGETParametersFromJSFToBackingBeans) for more info and examples.

Comment: Your blog looks great, thanks :)
Yes you are correct about the hint of @PostConstruct, I've reialized this note (and list it in my blog  http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2010/01/calling-session-beans-on-jsf-managed.html )

But one question here, What if I need to put the employee object in the session scope using the h:outputlink ?

Comment: Just make `EmployeeManager` a session scoped bean.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions I can think of:

1. Use JSF 2 (part of Java EE 6)
2. If you are stuck in JSF 1.x, use [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).

If it's possible to switch to a Java EE 6 server, I highly recommend option number 1.

**Edit**: There are 2 tags that were added in JSF 2: `<h:link />` and `<h:button />`. These use GET instead of POST. Also, look into `<f:viewparam />`. On top of this, there are *many* other wonderful additions in JSF 2. For a brief overview, see [this article](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/).

Comment: So, Is using JSF2 will solve this problem,as I am afraid after switching to still face the problem?

Comment: You don't necessarily need JSF2 for this. This makes no sense.

Comment: You don't *need* JSF 2 for this. You can modify your view handler to accept accept query parameters. However, this is a hacky way of doing it. You can also use an output link. However, that circumvents JSF navigation.